# Trying to refresh my knowledge of the Prototype Tree. What is wrong here?

Tags: javascript

According to http://js4py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/object-tree.html,

> All JavaScript objects are part of an inheritance tree. Each object in
>   the tree has a parent object, which is also called the prototype
>   object (of the child).

I was playing around to make sure I understand it correctly. Shouldn't the following print `"lakdas"` since `myOtherObj` inherits the field `x` from its parent `myObj`? Why does it instead log `undefined`?

```
var myObj = { x:"lakdas" };
var myOtherObj = { y:"lkjaas" };
myOtherObj.prototype = myObj;
console.log(myOtherObj.x); /* Should print "lakdas", right? */
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't change an object's prototype by assigning to a `prototype` property.  In many engines you can't change the prototype at all after the object is created.  You can set the prototype at object creation time:

```
var myObj = { x:"lakdas" };
var myOtherObj = Object.create(myObj); // sets prototype
myOtherObj.y = "lkjaas";
console.log(myOtherObj.x); // prints "lakdas"
```

*Functions* have a `prototype` property - when you use a function as a constructor, the object stored in the function's `prototype` property becomes the prototype of the constructed object:

```
var myObj = { x:"lakdas" };
function foo() {
  this.y = "lkjaas";
}
foo.prototype = myObj;
var myOtherObj = new foo();
console.log(myOtherObj.x); // prints "lakdas"
```